# Что означает этот символ-®

Tags: символы

Помогите пожалуйста, что означает этот символ-®

Comment: [Знак правовой охраны товарного знака](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8B_%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0) (Гуглите)

Answer (score 1):

® - Знак правовой охраны товарного знака (ставится обычно справа вверху от товарного знака и подтверждает, что данный товарный знак официально зарегистрирован как принадлежащий исключительно данной фирме)

[источник](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C2%AE)

Answer (score 0):

Авторское право © и товарные знаки ®

https://sellme.biz/2005/01/avtorskoe-pravo-i-tovarnye-znaki-tm.html